# Node-sass creates extra files in watch mode

Tags: css, node.js, npm, node-sass, npm-cli

I import all my SCSS styles into a index.scss file using @import. This works fine when I build css manually using npm run build-css:

```
"scripts": {
    //Other scripts
    "build-css": "node-sass src/scss/index.scss -o dist/css/",
  }
```

When I run node-sass in watch mode it updates the /dist/css/index.css just fine but also creates the css in the dist folder for the original scss file that I edited and imported in the src/scss/index.scss

```
"scripts": {
        //Other scripts
        "build-css": "node-sass src/scss/index.scss -o dist/css/",
        "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/scss/index.scss -o dist/css/ -w src/scss/**/*.scss --include-path src/scss/imports/*.scss"
      }
```

My src/scss/index.scss looks as follows:

```
@import "./imports/bootstrap.min";
@import "./imports/contacts";
```

So, if I edit contacts.scss in watch mode node-sass updates the ./dist/css/index.css but also creates an extra contacts.css in the dist/css folder.

Is there a way I can have node-sass update only the dist/css/index.css and not build the imports into the dist folder?

Comment: Maybe `-w` uses the changed files as input as well?

Comment: Yes -w can watch for specified files. But my issue is I want to watch all the files but build only the index.css

Comment: I tried npm run build-css && node-sass src/scss/index.scss -o dist/css/ -w src/scss/index.scss but still the same result

Comment: What I meant is that I think the -w flag runs the compiler on all the files that change

Comment: Yes that is true. Is there a way I can detect changes in all the scss files and restrict the build to only index.scss?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, my apologies regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the filename `contacts.scss` to `_contacts.css`; the compiler ignores the underscored files.